# commutator subspace as an ideal

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory

$k$ is a commutative ring, $k$-algebra $M_n(k)$ has the commutator subspace $[M_n(k), M_n(k)]$. The ideal generated by the commutator subspace is all of $M_n(k)$.

Is there something off with this statement. So it means the commutator subspace has to include the identity matrix. But it doesn't. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement just means that for some matrices $A_1,...,A_r,B_1,...,B_s, A_1',...,A_r',B_1',...,B_s'\in M_n(k)$ and $C,D\in [M_n(k),M_n(k)]$, $\sum A_iCA_i'+\sum B_jDB_j'=I_n$. It does not mean $I_n\in [M_n(k),M_n(k)]$.